# Orientation change not working

Tags: javascript, device-orientation

I am trying to get size and position of an image when I rotate my device but it always appears the same.

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(evt) {
    var height = $('#imgg').height();
    var width = $('#imgg').width();
    alert(height);
    alert(width);
    var position = $('#imgg').position();

    alert('left: ' + position.left + ', top: ' + position.top);

});
```

Comment: Well of course the size and position would be the same when you rotate the device. What are you expecting to happen? The width/height of the screen will change but individual elements on the page will not.

Comment: Hi Dave, when rotate device allways size change because i think that css media queries change position , top and lefth ...

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Can you please include your css and maybe a jsfiddle to demonstrate this?